# C++ Factor Program: Outputting Number of Factors Given

Tags: c++

I am writing a simple program that finds the factors of a list of integers through Linux Redirection. I am almost done, but I am stuck on one part. Here is my program so far:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()

{
int counter = 0;
int factor;
cin >> factor;

while (cin)
{
if (factor < 0)
break;
cout << "The factors of " << factor << " are " << endl;
for(int i=factor; i>=1; i--)
if (factor % i == 0)
  {
    counter++;
    cout << i << endl;
  }
cout << "There are " << " factors." << endl;
cout << endl;
cin >> factor;
}
return 0;
}
```

Now the problem I have is in the line " cout << "There are " << " factors." << endl; ". I'm not sure how to calculate the number of factors output by the program.

For example:

The factors of 7 are

1

7

There are 2 factors.

How would I go about calculating and outputting the "2" in this example.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you are *copying* a simple program *from someone else*, because you could not possibly have written the above code yourself *without* knowing in which variable you are already storing the information you want.

Comment: Also WTH is "Linux Redirection"?

Comment: Well, I do have examples of programs similar to this in my lecture notes, but I'm having trouble figuring this out. I'm not sure why you're so quick to accuse me of copying someone else's code.

Comment: Linux Redirection is taking input from a file rather than a user. Hence, there is no prompt for a number to find factors for.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
cout << "There are " << " factors." << endl;
```

use

```
cout << "There are " << counter << " factors." << endl;
```

If you do that, you have to move the line where you define `counter`.

Instead of it being the first line in `main`, it needs to be moved to be the first line in the `while` loop.

Comment: Nevermind. I forgot to move it to the first line in while. It worked out. Thank you for your help!